# Why doesn't Stack Overflow require e-mail confirmation?

Tags: support, openid, email

It is possible to log in with my Yahoo OpenID (which is tied to my Yahoo e-mail account), and then create a new unregistered user with the same e-mail address, so that both accounts are connected to the same e-mail. Why is that allowed? Shouldn't Stack Overflow have some sort of e-mail confirmation?

Comment: This is not something that SO can influence in any way, is it? It's simply that the two OpenID providers don't check for cross-duplicates. Nor should they, really.

Comment: @Pekka I don't use the yahoo email for the myopenid, so even if the openid providers would do this, it wouldn't matter, I've entered the yahoo email on the user edit page of SO

Comment: Ah, so you have two accounts with the same E-Mail address?

Comment: @Pekka yes, one e-mail yahoo used as OpenID, and another one that I entered on the user edit page for the second account (logged in with myopenid)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How many sockpuppets can a user work before getting the ban?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-many-sockpuppets-can-a-user-work-before-getting-the-ban)

Comment: @Omu do you have the "E-Mail" field filled twice with the same address?

Comment: @Straitjacket not really, that question is about having many accounts, this is about having many with same e-mail, notice the difference

Comment: @Pekka no, I login with yahoo but I can also login with gmail, and it's the same account, for these 2, my yahoo and gmail are merged into one, so when I login with yahoo I have the gmail email in use, I kinda get it now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your e-mail isn't the key to your account.  Your OpenID endpoint name is the key, and those are unique for your accounts.  The e-mail address is irrelevant, and does not need to be confirmed, because it was confirmed separately by your openID provider.

Comment: the thing is that you can use another email which wasn't confirmed by the openid provider, I do understand now that in the case when the users is not using openid but registers he is confirming his email and gets an unique SE openid anyway

Comment: Hasn't the recent change to the login system made email more important? As I understand it, if you have any email address associated with your account, you can login using any trusted OpenID that is associated with that email (facebook, gmail, stack exchange) even if you haven't previously associated it with your account.