# Some answers got unaccepted in my rep history but still display a checkmark

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, reputation-history, unaccepted-answer

My reputation listing is showing that on Mar 4 and 5, some of my answers got unaccepted, but when I go to those answers, they are still showing as accepted -- they still have the green check mark. Can somebody please explain what is happening with my profile?

[image: Reputation event list for Mar 4]

Here are three of the answers that are listed above:

[Getting MD5 and SHA-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006743/how-to-get-md5-and-sha1-in-objective-c-iphone/6006747#6006747)

[Creating a base-64 string from NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006823/how-to-get-base64-nsstring-from-nsdata/6006828#6006828)

[My custom font is not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255958/why-custom-font-is-not-working-in-iphone/6255972#6255972)

Comment: I've seen this before. It's a bug in the serial vote reversal script. A whole bunch of votes from this [user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/754229/user754229) to you were reversed. Accepts count as "votes". But the checkmark display on the answer seems to be cached and is not updated. If you mouse over the checkmark, it says "loading when this answer was accepted..."

Comment: Perhaps you answered a lot of one user's questions correctly (within a short period) and it decided that the user was serial accepting your answers?

Comment: @Mysticial: Looking at the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6006743/timeline) for one question confirms the answer is indeed unaccepted.

Comment: @Mysticial: And there is a [second user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/815075/user815075) involved as well. In total, 5 questions have been unaccepted between these two, and on both their profiles the 'accepted' status is cached as well.

Comment: @ProfPickle: Sure, but *why are they still marked as accepted*? That is the problem at hand here.

Comment: @Mart Because someone stayed up too long at night and wasn't thinking straight. I would suggest putting in a bug report :)

Comment: @ProfPickle: Good thing the OP put a `bug` tag on his post then. :-P

Comment: @Mart Sometimes I need to sleep more and think less.

Comment: And how did a user who hasn't been on the site in nearly 2 years either unaccept an answer or do any serial upvoting? :/

Comment: hello.. any moderator or stackexchange developer looking into this?

Comment: anyone looking into this bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The giveaway here is the last entry shown in that rep history: "Serial upvoting reversed" (now appears as "voting corrected"). When [extremely unusual voting patterns](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) are detected between two users, *all* votes between them may be revoked - including the Accept votes.

That doesn't alter the Accept *status* - the answer was still marked as accepted and we don't change that. But it does invalidate all reputation earned by both the asker and answerer for accepting the answer.

#### See also: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685)