# Some accepted answers appear to have been unaccepted but still have the checkmark

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, data-explorer, unaccepted-answer

Some accepted answers do not have a valid accept-vote in Votes table, even though the question owner still exists. Stack Overflow alone has over [2000](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220062/accepted-answers-without-accept-vote-where-question-owner-exists) such answers. A recent example is [Sub query for column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23137208/):

- The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23137208/timeline) says that the answer was unaccepted on July 3, 2014.
- However, it still has the green checkmark
- However, the checkmark does not show acceptance time on hover.

Is the answer accepted or not? Is it some kind of [Schrödinger's acceptance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)?

Comment: This may be related to [Some answers got unaccepted in my rep history but still display a checkmark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170883/), but I'm not sure it's the same bug: that question is about serial unacceptance of some kind.

Comment: Could be a merge....  Questions can't have more than one selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the serial voting reversal process got too greedy and removed the raw accept vote along with "real" upvotes:

> [image]

Most likely a bug when there are invalid upvotes on an accepted answer.

This gets more serious for [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257553/tushar?tab=reputation):

> [image]

Comment: Aha, so my query detects serial upvoters? Presumably the question owner took part in serial voting, why else would acceptance be invalidated... Hmm. By the way, if you view second user's rep changes [sorted by post](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2257553/tushar?tab=reputation&sort=post), you'll see `-555  6 events >` but clicking the expand arrow says "no net reputation changes". Yet another bug.

Comment: I edited [the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220062) to include the user who asked the question. An interesting list, with a lot of repetition. Not all of these are serial voters, though: sometimes the accepted answer is by question owner, and it seems in this case no accept-vote is recorded.

Comment: @900 guess only a dev can know for sure, but looks like you stumbled into a bug of some sort, yeah. :)