# Show what new users see when asking?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

I heard you guys have done some awesome development to help steer newbies in the right direction.

Would it be possible for us 'trusted' users to have a CheckBox control to toggle newbie help? **When we ask questions?**

<sub>Asking for a friend.</sub>

Comment: Would using a sock puppet for your cardboard box plays help? To be serious though, why would this functionality be useful?

Comment: What problem is this solving? Feature requests should explain how this is valuable to the community. What about this feature makes things better? Be more specific about what you mean by "newbie help"? What, specifically, do you want to see?

Comment: @who There are developments in that space us trusted users can't see. I don't have any sock puppets. Why else would one ask??

Comment: The obvious answer is to make a sockpuppet purely for test purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to see this experience to write my course on Stack Exchange, so I spent some time not logged in, and I set up a sock puppet just so that I could record the process of signing up for an account, and the low-rep experience. However I got permission before I did so.

In general, just going to a beta site and signing up is going to be the easiest way. I understand that sometimes Stack Overflow is specifically different, so if you have a good reason for wanting to see the new user experience, email the team and get permission for a temporary sock puppet.

Comment: _"I got permission before I did so"_ Explicit permission should not be needed; see [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/159251), noting the last paragraph **"You mentioned valid uses for sockpuppets; what are they? [...] reminding yourself what the site "feels like" for someone with only the basic abilities"**

Comment: Agreed, but if you intend to interact beyond a simple asking, such as commenting and voting, it can't hurt to be clear you're not up to anything nefarious. Plus, my socks are detected by the community within minutes so mods being aware helps.

Comment: We do not need permission to create more accounts, that's a waste of the team time, in my opinion. As long as the accounts don't vote for each other or doing something giving us more power than we should have (e.g. flagging same post twice), it's totally OK.

Comment: I agree that it is not necessary to contact the team, but explaining the puppet's purpose and affiliations on its profile page might help to avoid some possible confusion later on. (Like if someone happened to think it was an _evil_ sock puppet)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to know what a site looks like for a new user, create a sock puppet account. The guidelines for how to use a sock puppet are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/159251) and they *are* 100% OK *if* you use them correctly.

Consider identifying yourself on the user page and linking to your primary account (if you're OK with the connection... this isn't required but can help if you're not trying to hide the account). Absolutely avoid doing anything between the two accounts that you couldn't do with a single account. The guidelines in the FAQ are to not do the following things:

> - Voting on your own posts
> - Answering your own questions with the other account(s)
> - Casting multiple votes on others' posts
> - Supporting your own arguments (*"+1: Shog is right, don't know why the rest of you don't realize this"*)
> - Using bounties to circumvent the rep cap
> - Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc.

If you aren't doing any of these things, you probably won't have any issues with your sock puppet account at all. Many, many users, including many moderators and CMs have sock puppet accounts for various reasons and seeing the site as a new user is one of those reasons.

Another alternative is to use an incognito/private browsing window to look at the site as an *unregistered* user. This doesn't require creating an account but *should* give you much the same experience.