# Would this two-account situation be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, sock-puppets

## Disclaimer: I know self-answers are encouraged. Take extra/illicit/morally reprehensible/dishonest rep gain out of the equation.

**This discussion will inform my actions on a similar online community.**

"While we discourage opinions on our main sites, questions here are likely to generate discussion and involve opinions." Where is the discussion?

I know sometimes sockpupetting is illegal. I also know it's sometimes legal. So here's the scenario.

Accounts will

- Disclose association when asked

Accounts may

- Answer a question asked by another account

Accounts will never

- Vote
- Edit
- Flag
- Comment (except to disclose association when asked)
- Talk in chat (except to disclose association when asked)
- Accept each others answers
- Offer bounties on each others answers
- Participate in voting rings etc.
- Deny association
- Ask questions twice as to circumvent duplicate flagging process
- Do anything illegal or morally reprehensible not mentioned above

Ethical? **Please** *discuss* ethics.

I have read the entirety of the question and answer that Mr. Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog
has very kindly suggested.

Comment: Question is, *why*? You are allowed to post self-answers to your own questions, and reputation from votes would be consolidated under one account rather than split across two, which would give you privileges faster.

Comment: Thought experiment. Also, help understand ethics.

Comment: The same general policy applies here: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange). In general, if it allows you to do things that you couldn't otherwise do using a single main account, it's not allowed and unethical.

Comment: No, not duplicate. Very specific case presented here.

Comment: Edited my comment. Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of canonical questions if the answer to that question also addresses this question. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Comment: Mr. Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog I want to make sure I don't do anything morally wrong.

Comment: The moral policy is the same as the site policy.

Comment: "*in general*, if it allows you to do things that you couldn't otherwise do using a single main account, it's not allowed and unethical. " Consider specifics of "testing bugs that only show up at low rep levels" Now consider specifics of OP

Comment: Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog: Does Meta not consider specific cases? We talk in chat, better?

Comment: Can you please [edit] this with more details about what *exactly* your purpose is? Right now, your question is extremely vague as there are both legitimate and illegitimate uses of doing what you're doing, and we need more information.

Comment: Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog: Done.

Comment: Your new sentence "*This discussion will inform my actions on a similar online community*" doesn't really explain what *specific* actions you're planning to take. It would be very nice if you edit this question with *specific details* on what "experiment" you're going to run, and *how* your behavior will be influenced. As currently written, there isn't much more to say than what's in the site policy.

Comment: Site and Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog: What is one illegal action that fits the constraints? One legal action?

Comment: In all honesty, it would be less time-consuming for us if we knew what specific thing you're planning to do so we can tell you if it fits the policy, rather than keeping it from us and thus keeping your question vague.

Comment: Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog: Let me say this, competing Q&A site. I do not wish to carry this conversation there.

Comment: Sonic the Inclusive Hedgehog, again: What is one illegal action that fits the constraints? One legal action? With your answer, I can be more specific.

Comment: I will flag this post to be closed as it is unclear what you are actually asking..

Comment: Hi SuperHeliPower! If this is about a competing Q&A site, please ask there. This site is for questions about the Stack Exchange Network, not for helping you understand the ethics of competitors.

Comment: Welp, at least they deleted their account. That was probably the best result we could have hoped for

Answer (score 11):

> Answer a question asked by another account

I would advise against this. Technically, it shouldn't make a difference, but users tend to judge self-answers differently than situations where the answerer and the questioner are two different persons. Since that's a given, you're essentially misleading other users, which is heavily frowned upon if not outright forbidden. In any case, most people here consider it unethical.

> Disclose association when asked

Yes, it *might* work when put a giant disclaimer at the top the answer. But **why** are you posting the answer under a different account then? I can't think of a proper reason to do so. If you need your sockpuppet to earn some reputation, just ask *and* answer the question with the sockpuppet account. If you want to do it to "circumvent implicit moderator biases due to nickname choices", that's misleading, so the first paragraph explains that it's unethical.

Comment: ? Accounts will never  accept each others answers; to circumvent implicit moderator biases due to nickname

Comment: Glorfindel: See edits

Comment: I'm not saying it's unethical, under the very strict conditions you mention. I'm just wondering what's the point in doing so...

Comment: <s>Thought experiment and potential use in circumventing implicit moderator biases due to nickname choices.</s> Thought experiment.

Comment: @SuperHeliPower Circumvention of any type falls under the definition of being able to do something that you wouldn't otherwise be able to do under a single account you own, and thus the general sock puppet policy is applicable here.

Comment: My b, circumvent nothing. Consider situation as posed in the OP.

Comment: Glorfindel: What is one illegal action that fits the constraints? One legal action?

Comment: Glorfindel: Please clarify might. Suppose I always put a giant disclaimer at the top the answer. Why "might" work? What is a case where might not work?

Comment: Be prepared to receive downvotes on such an answer because some other users dislike sockpuppets.

Comment: Glorfindel: "some other users dislike sockpuppets" Can you please expand on that?

Comment: No, I can't. Please read up on other sockpuppet questions on this site, the topic has its own tag. Then draw your own conclusions...

Answer (score 10):

Just to reiterate and emphasise what others have written. This:

> Accounts may
>
> - Answer a question asked by another account

is not allowed on any Stack Exchange site.

There is nothing wrong with self answering so there is no need to create a second account to do this.

If you are found doing this then you risk having the second account deleted and the main account suspended.