# What should I do if I see a new account from a suspended user?

Tags: support, moderators, users

Yesterday, a contributor (questioner) on a site was suspended for 365 days. That very same person, with a thinly veiled avatar change, returns today as if nothing has happened! It would appear that it's OK for this to happen. What's going on here?

Comment: If someone is suspended and they create a new account, that's not ok. Nowhere in the rules will you find that's ok.

Comment: However, unless that new account starts causing trouble there's a low likelihood of anything being done against it.

Comment: @Mast - So, this could continue, with avatar changes, ad infinitum?

Comment: An avatar change does not create a new user. The suspension is on the account.

Comment: @Mast - so a new account must have been created. Maybe new rule needed?

Comment: See also: [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> It would appear that it's OK for this to happen.

No, it's certainly not OK. It's just that the ♦ moderators didn't notice the new account yet – they're not online 24/7. You can flag one of the posts for moderator attention and explain that's a suspended user breaking the rules.

[image]

I did that just before writing this answer, and the new account has now been destroyed.

Comment: How did you find the user to flag? (Was it a job for the SEDE query again? :) )

Comment: I just looked at the homepage of the site where the OP is the most active, and found a question with some suspicious comments.

Comment: Elementary, I guess. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the hand drawn red circle. People have gotten lax around here.

Comment: Some of us still follow the old ways 