# Can I swap Solstice (Sun) with Solstice (Moon) hat?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I earned the Solstice (Sun) hat but I would like the Solstice (Moon) hat instead. Is there any way to swap between them?

Comment: You can't, it was never possible in any winter bash. The type is determined randomly when hat awarded, and set to the account.

Comment: I'd trade you my moon if it were allowed.

Comment: @Glorfindel I also considered this as dupe, however it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars maybe not directly, but it probably does if you can do 1+1. Oh well, I'll write a more specific answer, that shouldn't hurt. Thanks!

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah that's much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All we know as community, i.e. without looking at the source code, it's that it's likely to be tied to your network account ID, which you can find in the [URL of your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current):

> Last year we had a hat referencing ["the dress"](https://www.wired.com/2015/02/science-one-agrees-color-dress/), which at the time was a hugely popular meme. The hat that could be won would be black and blue or white and gold depending on the user receiving it. Well, a little known secret is that this was achieved by using looking up the bit corresponding to each user's account id in a file, and that file was an actual image of the dress. Pretty neat, eh?

<sub>([source](https://sklivvz.com/posts/i-built-a-hardware-rng-for-christmas) - Sklivvz was one of the developers back then)</sub>

So the only way to get the other type of hat would be creating a new account, qualify for the Solstice hat, and hope you get the one you want. Except that it's already too late, the Solstice is over ... and you need to be [careful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/295232) with alternate accounts. Since this is a <s>fan</s> CM favorite, it might work next year, who knows ...