# How can I manage multiple work accounts with my personal Stack Exchange account?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

#### Information

Recently I joined a charity organization which requires me to do some light coding.
I setup of my new account on Chrome which now has three accounts linked in it (*Personal*, *9-5 Work*, and *Charity*). Now when I click on log in with Google on Stack Exchange (really the only way I log into Stack Exchange), I'm now logged in as the user profile that Chrome is currently set to which in the case of my charity account is a new account without any reputation.

I like that I get notified in my work e-mail about notices contained with my "work" Stack Exchange site and that my personal notifications only get forwarded to my personal e-mail. This helps me keep focused on the task at hand and not get distracted by questions related to other projects.

My accounts don't interact with each other and when it was just my work and personal, it didn't bother me to rebuild my reputation to get privileges. Now I'm realizing I'll need to do this each time I change jobs and or when I join a new organization.

#### Question / feature request (if no solution currently exists)

How can people manage multiple accounts based on the work that surrounds the account? Is there a way to let Stack Exchange know **on registration** that this account is for a user/profile that already exists, but that it needs to be kept distinct due to the work being done. (I assume that this would need to be done on registration so to minimize rep farming: only merging accounts after they have accrued a positive reputation points or buying accounts to increase reputation points.)

If possible I'd like a way to aggregate my reputation across all accounts (to prevent having to rebuild each time) while keeping the e-mail account notified of updates distinct.

#### Additional information

Each profile has its own e-mail: [my.email@workdomain.com], [my.email@personal.com], [my.email@charity.com] which I'd like to keep as distinct recipients for notification sent by Stack Exchange are related to posts done by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've maintained a second account and haven't had them merged yet.

Aside from the 'obvious' - as per [Shog's writeup from way back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange), my recommendation would be, unless you have an obvious reason not to, to *clearly label* your accounts as yours.

With [Aibobot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/358125/aibobot?tab=profile) it is/was an account used for untrusted systems and testing. I went above and beyond and labelled the account with the purpose, and the 'main' account.

As such - mentioning the main account, that its for 'work'/'working with organisation' should generally be really helpful should a moderator wonder what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, for this. Is there a specific location for me to state that this is a secondary main account (not puppet because I use it normally between 9-5) or should I just include a line somewhere in the bio or else where on my profile page?

Comment: I used my bio - which is why I linked my alternate account.